# How can we add Release version of our site in web.config of Wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress

How can we add Release version of our site in web.config of Wordpress site. I want to add Version number in web.config of Wordpress site and show it in footer. Also want
to reflect release date with it. Can please anyone assist me to fix it.

Comment: Isn't `web.config` an Internet Information Services configuration file? Why should it contain a version number?

Comment: @chris Can you please suggest than any alternative to show version number.

Comment: Can you not just make a `version.php` file and include it where needed?

Comment: @Chris As we can update our web.config. Is it not possible to include this code and show   <appSettings>
  <add key="version" value="1.0" />
</appSettings>

Comment: Theoretically, yes you can do that, but then you have to write a parser for the `web.config` file.

Comment: @Chris Thanks but I am new to Wordpress. Can you please explain in detail. Please add some code so that I can get idea. Thanks again.

Comment: It's just an XML document, so if you really want to parse it (although again I think it's a bad idea) then use an XML parser.